# asp:Label change visible from C# and JS code at the same time

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, visible

I have asp:Label. 
How can I change visible from C# and js code?

Can have:

```
style="display: none;"
```

or

```
Visible="false"
```

If use first way, couldn't change visible from C# code,

if use second way, couldn't change visible  from JS code.

I need have opportunity to change visible from C# and JS code at the same time.
C#:

```
MyPanel.Visible = true;
```

JS:

```
 $('.MyPanel').show();
```

Comment: Why? Visible on the server-side means whether or not the thing is even sent to the client; client-side just styles it as hidden. Considering the latter can serve both being there and still not visible, what's the use case?

Comment: if you can set visibility in C#, `visibility = 'hidden/visible'` in javscript should serve your purpose

Comment: try setting visibility as `document.getElementBbyId("yourId").style.display = "none";` then it should be possible to `Visible="false";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set its style attributes using C# and then use js to change it back

```
MyPanel.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
```

Then on the client side you can call what you declared already.

```
$('.Mypanel').show(); // i'm assuing you've add a class on the 'MyPanel' element.
```